# defined('_JEXEC') or die in Joomla Plugin

Tags: joomla

Hy

We have following Problem:
Our editors-xtd plugin have the following files:

```
pluginname.php
pluginname.xml
modal.php
processor.php
```

for security reasons and the listing in the JED, we have to include `

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
```

Because there is no way to call the modal.php and the processor.php inside joomla, how can we handle this. 
To build a component to call the files over the modal iframe, would be the only way, we see at the moment. But to write a component, to call a modal iframe is a litte bit "overpowered".

So if someone has an idea, please tell us!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you've got the following:

An editor-xtd plugin `pluginname.php` which produces some HTML/CSS/JS output. This in turn calls (through AJAX?) the other php files `modal.php` and `processor.php` directly, without going through Joomla's index.php. Since execution does not go through Joomla's code before it hits those files, _JEXEC is not defined, and thus the process `die`s.

There are two solutions to this.

1. Don't check for _JEXEC. If your modal.php and processor.php do not hit the database or need other parts of Joomla, there is no real need to go through the Joomla framework. In short: if you don't include any Joomla files in that part of the code, I don't see a problem with this. I'm not sure, however if JED editors agree with this opinion.
2. Go through the Joomla Framework the proper way. Create a component, give it a view, put the modal.php login into that view. Call that view from the editor-xtd plugin. Do the equivalent with `processor.php` (according to whatever that piece of code actually does)